# Limit x and y with sequelize js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'd like to know how to make a Sequelize query to get specific posts of my blog between for example 10 and 20...

My code below is showing the last ten posts...

```
dbContext.post.findAll({order: 'id DESC', limit: 10 /*10,10?*/, where: {state: 1}}).success(function(posts) {
    callback(posts);
});
```

Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want, you have to combine `limit` and `offset` options. The `offset` option lets you step over the `n` number of elements you pass to it. Try that:

```
dbContext.post.findAll({
  where: {
    state: 1
  },
  order: 'id DESC',
  offset: 10,
  limit: 10
}).success(function (posts) {
  callback(posts);
});
```

This will return will skip the first 10 elements, and return elements from 11 to 20.